Cannot get values of columns in where function of update operation - Kotlin Dataframe
I'm trying to use update to change values in cells like in the tables below. I want consecutive duplicates of a set of columns to be replaced with nulls. Is there a way to do this other than what I'm trying below? There is an issue with the update operation's where function in which just a single column from update's parameters is in scope for the row condition for evaluation of the condition. The it variable has the value for a single column from update's parameters at a time. Additionally, using the column accessor variable as in the example below doesn't get the value for the columns in the where block as I would like.
val col1 by column<String>()
val col2 by column<String>()
dataframe
    .update("col2")
        .where { col1 == prev()?.get("col1") && col2 == prev()?.get("col2") }
        .with { null }
    .update("col1")
        .where { col1 == prev()?.get("col1") }
        .with { null }

Base data



col1
col2
col3




abc
1234
X


abc
1234
Y


abc
5678
X


abc
9012
X


def
1234
X


def
1234
Y


def
1234
Z



Target data



col1
col2
col3




abc
1234
X


null
null
Y


null
5678
X


null
9012
X


def
1234
X


null
null
Y


null
null
Z



I tried using it in the where function but it references a single column value in the update operation's parameters within the scope of where. The column accessor variables don't get the value of the columns as I validated from results of another update operation. It would be helpful if values for multiple columns in a row can be used in the row condition within where as this would help to perform my udpate requirement.
